# Como posso setar ranges em Ionic com um valor inicial pré-determinado?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Coloquei um Range para definir hora e minutos. Como mostro na view, mas, apesar de setar o "value" no sistema o range sempre começa no meio e sem valor.

Como posso setar meus ranges para estarem lá no começo, com o valor que quero?

```
     <div class="item range">
                        Horas
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="24" value="1" step="1" ng-model="configura.hora_prazo_min">
                        <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>
                    </div>

                    <p><b>Horas: </b>{{configura.hora_prazo_min}}</p>



                    <div class="item range">
                        Minutos
                        <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="0" step="1" ng-model="configura.minutos_prazo_min" >
                        <i class="icon ion-clock"></i>
                    </div>

                    <b>Minutos:  </b>{{configura.minutos_prazo_min}}   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi na verdade falta de atenção minha. Tinha que ter criado os models após o array:

```
$scope.configura = [];

        $scope.configura.hora_prazo_min = 0;
        $scope.configura.minutos_prazo_min = 0;
```